# AngularJS - Ng-repeat - Select2 JS - Issue setting default value

Tags: angularjs-select2

```
Having trouble in setting up the default value for the drop down when AngularJS/ng-repeat/custom directive + Select2 JS is used.

1. I avoided using ng-options as the directive priority is 0.
2. I tried setting the priority for the custom directive 'select2Directive' to a number less than 1000, but still no luck.
```

Plunker @ http://plnkr.co/edit/Csy5FqDSQbErTm2fNPac. Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: okay, finally i solved the issue using a timeout.                $timeout(function () {scope.$apply(select2Inst.select2('val',attrs['directive-name'])); },0);

Comment: updated plunker with working version:

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that you are calling the select2 using a small directive, but I found this library named [angular-select2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2) which is easy to implement as well.

you can set the default values with your ng-model/$scope, take a lookt to this plunker to get the idea

http://plnkr.co/edit/pFkY5f?p=preview

EDIT:

I'd rather try to pass the data in other way seems like the select2 data and your the ng-repeat are not in sync

you could try a different approach something like creating a directive and insert the data from there.

```
directive('select2Dynamic', function ($timeout) {
    return { 
        restrict: 'A', 
        priority: 1,
        scope: {
            ngModel: "="
          }, 
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {

           var select2Inst = element.select2();
                   select2Inst.select2({data:scope.$parent.$eval(attr.ngModel)}); 
                   select2Inst.select2('val',attr['select2Dynamic']);
        }
      }
    });

<select select2-dynamic='2' ng-model='addresses' id="address" name="address" style="width:200px;" >
</select>
```

if you want to stick to your approach you'll consider to set up the value and the end of the "model binding event"

look at this [plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/yNXS2/)

anyway I still stand my point that you should try angular-select2 library

hope that helps

Comment: My requirement is different. I have to display the selected values in the drop down list box. I really dont want to go for a third party library for a simple directive which we can build with very few lines of code.

Comment: Agree with your alternative suggestion @jack. But as i said earlier my requirement is different and i have the directive implemented in multiple places with in my application. My solution works and requires couple of lines of code in the directive declaration without the need for editing any controllers as you suggested.

Comment: I'm glad to read that you sorted that out, it would be great if you can edit your question and post the plunker just as a reference to help any other devs that may (or not) stumble with your scenario.